# How to display enum names on table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

How can I display my enum's name in the table ? I created 2 variables called IsAdmin and IsActive as a int in database. I created enum files. When admin wants to add user , he/she can choose IsAdmin and IsActive enums and display their enum names but when it comes to show my all users in table , I can't see their names only the integer values. How can I fix this ?
(I researched this a lot I added a GetAttribute() method to display enum names but I can't display this metod in index , so it's not working.)
**Enums**

```
   public enum IsActive
    {
        [Display(Name = "Account Activated")]
        Active=1,
        [Display(Name = "Account is not Active")]
        Passive=2
    }
   public enum IsAdmin
    {
        [Display(Name = "Admin")]
        Admin = 1,
        [Display(Name = "User")]
        User= 2
     
    }
```

**AddUser**

```
<form method="post">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.IsAdmin, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(LibraryManagementSystem.Enums.IsAdmin)), "Choose")
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.IsActive, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(LibraryManagementSystem.Enums.IsActive)), "Choose")
    <br />
</form>
```

[image]

**ShowUsers/Index**

```
@using LibraryManagementSystem.Models
@model List<Table_User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<h2>Users List</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>

        <th>Is Account Active?</th>
        <th>Admin or User?</th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
   
    <td>@item.IsActive</td>
    <td>@item.IsAdmin</td>
    
    <td>
        <a href="/Admin/UserUpdate/@item.UserID" class="btn btn-danger">Uptade</a>
       
    </td>
</tr>
    }

</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks fine. Able to show the name instead of number. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7CGsOo)

Comment: @YongShun but it's not. I just added the screenshots of my views

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution if you want to just display the Enum's DisplayName attribute is to add

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumType), item.Enum))
```

Or if you want some additional flexibility and extensibility, I would suggest adding an extension method for retrieving the display name

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets human-readable version of enum.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>DisplayAttribute.Name of given enum.</returns>
public static string GetDisplayName<T>(this T enumValue) where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument not of type Enum");
    }

    DisplayAttribute displayAttrivute = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString()).First().GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();

    return displayAttribute?.GetName() ?? enumValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumType), item.Enum)) in this code what's the EnumType ? I get error as 'The type or namespace 'EnumType' could not be found'

Comment: @vives this would be your IsActive or IsAdmin enums, and equally, the `item.Enum` would be IsActive and IsAdmin respectively

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(Enum), item.IsActive)) i wrote it just like this but when I start it it says  'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.' I added my files screenshot. I think I wrote it  typeof(Enum) wrong

Comment: I would instead use `Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumType), item.Enum)` as a standalone item, as opposed to with the HTML templating method